# python 2.7 not working when I use it with sudo

Tags: linux, python-2.7, centos6

I am trying to install python2.7 on a VM which is centos 6.5. I followed a following guide to install it

```
http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos/
```

However when I try to install run python as sudo i get the following error.

```
-bash: python2.7: command not found
```

running just python2.7 works. It even works when i run it as a root user. Also I noticed that:

```
which python2.7
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/which: no python2.7
```

when I do sudo -i and then run the command.

Any idea why it is like that?

Comment: Where is python2.7 installed, and what's your `$PATH`?

Comment: its installed in /usr/local/bin/python2.7 and $PATH is /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/yazmataz/bin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using CentOS 6.5, this is likely due to the fact that `sudo` does not set `/usr/local/bin` as part of the `PATH`.

CentOS 6.x's `/etc/sudoers` file sets the `secure_path` (which is used during `sudo` sessions) to a very restricted set of paths.

Use the `visudo` command and look at the contents of your `/etc/sudoers` file. You will likely find this section:

```
#
# Adding HOME to env_keep may enable a user to run unrestricted
# commands via sudo.
#
# Defaults   env_keep += "HOME"

Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

So `sudo` doesn't use the `/usr/local/bin` path.

You can solve your problem in a couple ways:

1. Add `/usr/local/bin` to the `secure_path` - This can open up security problems if you don't know what's gonna be in your `/usr/local/bin` directory. Though typically, this is probably not a huge concern because only root has write access to `/usr/local/bin` by default.
2. Disable `secure_path` entirely by commenting it out - again, you're overriding a feature designed to restrict access and improve security.

Comment: I guess i will choose the option one since it seems to be better. Do I have to do anything else after making changes? like reloading something?

Comment: I have tried your solution but its still wont work. I tried rebooting the system and still its the same.

Comment: @hjelpmig - well, as it turns out, `secure_path` overrides anything else, so `env_keep` will have no effect. Go with option #2 (or the now-edited option #1).

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH python2.7
```

What this does is copy the current path you have into your new `sudo`'s environment.